# Relação Ternária Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent, modelo-relacional

Estou criando um sistema de enquetes onde tenho as seguintes tabelas.
Uma enquete tem várias opções.
Uma opção pertece apenas a uma enquete.
Um usuário pode votar em várias enquetes, mas uma opção por enquete.
Logo fiz

Model User

```
public function options(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Option::class);
}
```

Model Survey

```
public function options(){
  return $this->hasMany(Option::class);
}
```

Model Option

```
public function survey(){
  return $this->belongsTo(Survey::class,'survey_id');
}

public function users(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

Sabendo em qual option ele votou eu faço uma busca por essa option e exibo as enquetes que ele está participando, gostaria de exibir também a quantidade de total votos que ela tem até o momento, trazendo todas as option daquela enquete, pegando cada option dessa e somando quantos user_id tem cada, seria muito complicado, então resolvi fazer uma relação ternária.

```
        Schema::create('option_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('option_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('survey_id');


        $table->foreign('user_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');


        $table->foreign('option_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('options')->onDelete('cascade');

      $table->foreign('survey_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('survey')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Como faço para inserir e buscar os elementos dessa tabela, exemplo buscar as surveys que este usuário votou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode utilizar o método whereHas

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

```
$user_id  = Auth::user()->id;


$surveys = App\Survey::whereHas('options', function ($query) use ($user_id) {
    $query->where('user_id', '=', $user_id );
})->get();
```